# Tracking in_app_purchases event for subscriptions on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-analytics

Google [docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) say:

> This event is triggered only by versions of your app that include the Firebase SDK. Note: paid app-purchase revenue, subscription revenue (Android only), and refunds are not automatically tracked. Your reported revenue may differ from the values you see in the Google Play Developer Console. Events that are flagged as being invalid or as sandbox (test) are ignored. Only iOS events are flagged as sandbox. Learn more about testing Google Play billing.

In other words in Android only subscriptions events are not tracked automatically. Is there a way how to track them? Do you have any implementation examples?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Google Analytics for Firebase does not track subscription based purchases on Android automatically. It does track subscription based purchases automatically on iOS.

The way to track subscription based purchases is to log a custom [ecommerce_purchases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE) event and provide the necessary CURRENCY and VALUE parameters. Please note that you need to [link Firebase to Google Play](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038?hl=en&ref_topic=6317497).

Just to update, as per reports - the Firebase team is actively working on bringing the subscription based purchases to be automatically tracked by the Firebase Android SDK.

Comment: " the Firebase team is actively working on bringing the subscription based purchases to be automatically tracked by the Firebase Android SDK"...
6 months later...

Answer (score 0):

These are tracked for you [in the Billing section of the Play Console without any further work. See the docs.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7391949)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Firebase enabled it's tracking for subscriptions recently. My observations: [Did Firebase start reporting in_app_purchase for subscriptions recently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786301/did-firebase-start-reporting-in-app-purchase-for-subscriptions-recently/56317225#56317225)