# Did Firebase start reporting in_app_purchase for subscriptions recently?

Tags: firebase, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

1. My Android app has integrated Firebase SDK
2. Firebase is linked to Google Play
3. I'm using subscriptions only
4. In the past there weren't any "*in_app_purchase*" events automatically reported (comparing to one-time products)
5. I do not report "*in_app_purchase*" manually from the client or server.

But I've got "in_app_purchase" recently with "*subscription*" (=1) parameter.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en lists next parameters: *product_id, product_name, price, price_is_discounted, value, currency, quantity, app_version*

Was there any changes in Firebase/GMS? Any blog posts/docs?

Comment: have you remember, test account subscription purchase is also reported under "in_app_purchase" event automatically?

Comment: sorry. don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Firebase did enable it recently. I'm seeing "in_app_purchase" events matching my own custom event started ~May 12. 
And description was changed on https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en.

> when a user completes an in-app purchase, **including an initial
>   subscription**, that is processed by the App Store on iTunes or by
>   Google Play